# Logstash exec plugin - available arguments

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

I have the following in my logstash configuration file:

```
input {
  file {
    path => "C:/myfile.txt"
  }
}

output {    
  exec {
    command => 'mytest.bat %message% %path%'
    interval => 0
 }
}
```

the `%message%` and `%path%` parameters are being passed to the batch file.

I am expecting to see:

- `message` contain the line of the input file currently being parsed
- `path` contain *C:/myfile.txt*

However, this is what the batch file recieves:

`message` *"%message%"*

`path` "C:/logstash-1.5.0/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/bin"

What is correct way to define the placeholders for:

- the current line to be output
- the name of file being parsed

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Please modify your config to

```
input {
  file {
    path => "C:/myfile.txt"
  }
}

output {    
  exec {
    command => "mytest.bat %{message} %{path}"
    interval => 0
 }
}
```

If you want to get the field in the event, please use `%{message}` ,not `%message%`

Comment: Thanks, %{path} now gives the name of the input file; however, %{message} just outputs '%{message}'

Comment: Found the issue. %{message} does not seem to work with JSON

Comment: That is, if codec=json is defined in the logstash configuration, %{message} will not work. Without the codec stuff, it does. If the file contains json, %{message} will then give the first part of the json, but not all of it.

Comment: "%{message}" in quotes will give the complete json, but %{path} will not be set

Comment: Don't what you mean? What's your problem now?    %{XXX} will give all the value in the XXX field.

Comment: If the input file is Json, then path is not resolved. In order to get the full contents of the Json in the message variable, the variable must be surrounded by quotes like "%{message}"

Comment: Can you provide your sample log and full config? It's hard to figure out the problem you meet